# How to use text box as date in ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have an ASP.NET wizard where a user fills in their personal details and the values of the text boxes are inserted into a MS SQL record.
However, when inserting the record, I get the following error:

> SQL Server error #241: Conversion failed when converting date and/or
>   time from character string

Code:

```
string insertSQL;
insertSQL = "INSERT INTO member (";
insertSQL += "UserId, mem_dob,) ";
insertSQL += "VALUES (";
insertSQL += "@UserId, @mem_dob";
insertSQL += ")";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, con);

//Add the parameters.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", providerIdKeyString);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mem_dob", DateOfBirth.Text);
```

Any ideas the best way to fix? Should I not be using a text box but something else?
I wanted to keep the web form simple - it validates the dates OK so thought the date should be valid.

Thanks

Comment: How are you validating the Date in Web Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply parse the `Text` to a valid `DateTime`.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mem_dob", DateTime.Parse(DateOfBirth.Text));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Of course you should have already validated that the entered "date" is valid at this stage.

Comment: Thanks - see my comment in response above.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the date entered in your Text Box is an invalid date according to SQL.  Before attempting to add the date as a parameter, first check it's validity. e.g.

```
DateTime myDate;
if(textBox1.TryParse(DateOfBirth.Text, out myDate))
{
   // Date is valid.
} else
{
   // Take corrective actions to fix the date.
}
```

Simply attempting to parse the date without knowing whether it's valid or not will leave your application open to a failure, as you simply shouldn't trust the user to enter a valid date.

Comment: Thanks, but I validated the date in the wizard control.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime t;
String Date = String.Empty;
if (DateTime.TryParse(Date, out t))
{
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mem_dob", t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also found that this works:     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mem_dob", Convert.ToDateTime(DateOfBirth.Text)); but parse is probably better?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to create simple user-control that contains three dropdown controls - for day, month and year and a public property/method to set/get date. You may think about ASP.NET Ajax controls.

In case if you want to use `Textbox` then restrict the user input via `CompareValidator` control or some sort of JavaScript and regular expression.

To parse date string use DateTime.TryParse, or DateTime.ParseExact (DateTime.TryParseExact) method.

```
 string[] inputFormat = {"dd-MM-yy","dd/mm/yy","dd-MMM-yyyy"};
 string userDate = "31-12-11";
 DateTime date;
 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(userDate, 
                            inputFormat, 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            DateTimeStyles.None, 
                            out date))
            {
              //valid
            }
```